# React Native Navigation push pantalla desde la izquierda

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, push

Tengo una super duda, averigue por todos lados ,probe varias cosas y no estoy pudiendo hacerlo andar...
Lo que tengo que hacer es que cuando haga un push DE UNA UNICA VISTA, las otras deben ser tal cual estan, esta vista venga desde la izquierda hacia la derecha.

Probe pasando atributos como props

```
export const goToPageWithAnimation = async (componentId, page, props) => {
  await Navigation.push(componentId, {
    component: {
      name: page,
      passProps: props,
      options: {
        topBar: {
          visible: false,
          drawBehind: true,
        },
        animations: {
          push: {
            enabled: 'true',
            content: {
              startAlpha: 0,
              endAlpha: 1,
              duration: 3,
              interpolation: 'accelerate',
            },
          },
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Ese es codigo de ejemplo, no esta haciendo lo de venir de la izquierda hacia la derecha.
De todas formas no funciona.

Probe con este tambien

```
 static options(passProps) {
return {
  animations: {
    push: {
      content: {
        x: {
          from: -1000, to: 0, duration: 300
        },
        y: {
          from: 0, to: 0, duration: 300
        }
      }
    },
    pop: {
      content: {
        x: {
          from: 0, to: -1000, duration: 300
        },
        y: {
          from: 0, to: 0, duration: 300
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

No funciona... Que puedo hacer? o que estoy haciendo mal?

Aca dejo las versiones de RN

"react-native": "0.56.0",
 "react-native-navigation": "^2.11.0",

Comment: Te has guiado de [este issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1759)?

Comment: @GermanAlzate creeria que no, fue una recopilacion de varias paginas para llegar a lo que hice, de todas fornmas nada me funciono :C, ahora reviso el link